# What does this code do?

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() {
    var _this = this,
        original = _this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        _obj = args.shift(),
        func = function() {
            var _that = _obj;
            return original.apply(_that, args.concat(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(
            arguments, args.length)));
        };
    func.bind = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return Function.prototype.bind.apply(_this, args);
    }
    return func;
};
```

I know it's a bind function. But I don't understand it and what it's doing, specifically the `args.concat` part. What does `concat` do? Also, what does `.bind` method do that `.apply` and `.call` can't?

Comment: `bind` returns a function, `call` and `apply` call a function, they're different beasts. `bind` is used when you want to ensure a function that is going to be used later is called with a specific context, with the option to bind arguments to the function also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bind` function takes a function and ensures that it is *always* bound to a specific `this` value. The easiest example is in event handlers. By default, event handler's `this` value is bound to `window`. However, let's say that you want to use an object's method as a listener, and in that listener change some properties:

```
var thing = {
    answer : 4,
    listener : function() {
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}
window.onload = thing.listener;
```

On the onload event, instead of `thing.answer` being changed like intended, `window.answer` is now 42. So, we use `bind`:

```
window.onload = thing.listener.bind(thing);
```

So, `bind` returns a function, that when called, calls the original function, but with the specified `this` value.

`[].concat` simply adds the arguments to the array - so `[].concat(5, 4)` returns `[5, 4]`, and `[5, 4].concat([42])` returns `[5, 4, 42]`. In this case, it is used to concatenate arguments - you can pass arguments to the `bind` function that'll be passed as arguments when the function is called. The concatenation works so that when you call the binded function, the arguments you pass now are also passed along.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [*shim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29) for [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

> But I don't understand it and what it's doing, specifically the `args.concat` part. What does concat do?

[`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) concatenates two or more `Array`s (as well as other values to an `Array`).

> Also, what does `.bind` method do that `.apply` and `.call` can't?

It returns a reference to a function with `this` bound to whatever you desire.

```
var newFn = fn.bind(['a', 'b', 'c']);

// This will call `fn()` with the above `Array` as `this`.
newFn('first arg', 'second arg');
```

It is useful for currying, e.g. returning a function which has arguments already set (as beyond setting `this` in `bind()`, you can set default arguments).

Comment: The odd (or different anyway) part of it is that it adds a `.bind` property to the function being returned `func.bind = function() {...` so that if you invoke `.bind()` against a function that is the *result* of a `.bind()`, the prototyped `.bind()` is shadowed, and it always binds to the original function only. This is a deviation from the standard `.bind()`.

Comment: ...it also very strangely duplicates 2 of its variables, referencing the same item by a different name. And it discards arguments passed to the invocation of the bound function that are at the same indices as the original bound arguments. Very weird function.

Comment: @patrick I did notice that duplication straight away. Strange.